# Overriding jest mock using module factory parameter pattern

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm currently mocking my API component using jest's module factory parameter for jest.mock. My current mock looks like:

```
jest.mock('./api', () => {return function (request) {
 if (request.method === 'GET' && request.url === '/templates') {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve({
      data: { 
       success: true,
       requestId: 1
      }...
```

However, I don't know how to override a mock using this pattern for another test in which I want the return to be `success: false`. How do I override this mock to return a different set of data, in the style of "mockImplementationOnce" for another test?

Comment: Why not use `mockImplementationOnce` ? You should be able to do something like ```api().mockImplementationOnce(() => ...)```